# Why did Obi-Wan not know about Kamino and Kaminoans?

Tags: star-wars

If you watch Episode 2, you know Obi-Wan is asking his friend from the inn about the dart, and got told it's from Kamino. Then he acts like he knows nothing about Kamino or Kaminoans.

But how can he not know anything about them when there is a Kaminoan Jedi in Episode 1 in the council?

[image]

**How can there be a Kaminoan council member if no one really knows anything about Kamino?**

Answer (score 19):

Because Master Poof is not Kaminoan. Per the [*Star Wars Databank*](http://www.starwars.com/databank/yarael-poof), he is Quermian:

> A gaunt, long-necked Quermian, Yarael Poof had two brains and four arms, which he kept hidden beneath his Jedi robes. Poof was a member of the Jedi Council during the final years of the Republic, and was in the Jedi Council Chamber when Qui-Gon Jinn returned from Tatooine with the extraordinary news that the ancient Sith had returned to challenge the Jedi once more.

Although they cast a similar silhouette, Quermians and Kaminoans are quite different:

Here's a better picture of Master Yarael Poof:

[image: Master Yarael Poof]

And here's Lama Su and Taun We, from *Attack of the Clones*:

[image: Obi-Wan with Lama Su and Taun We and]

As you can see, they both share an elongated neck, which makes them appear very similar in low-visibility situations. However, there are a number of differences (both visual and non-visual):

- Master Poof has a more humanoid head (although he has no nose<sup>1</sup>), with a humanoid shape and humanoid eyes. The Kaminoans, on the other hand, have more fish-like heads: large black eyes and cranial ridges being two prominent differences
- Skin tone is dramatically different; Master Poof has a pigmentation similar to a (very) pale human, while the Kaminoans are more stark white
- As mentioned in the Databank quote above, Quermians had two brains and four arms. Although we can't confirm anything about Kaminoan internal organs, we can fairly confidently state that they only have two arms; with their predilection for form-fitting garments, where would they keep any extras?

---

<sup>1</sup> He's probably really tired of [that joke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=in7yLZJ7A6Y), too

Comment: People complaining about the name "Snoke" need to know that "Poof" was someone's name.

Comment: @WadCheber And that's not even, like, the *tenth* stupidest name in *Star Wars*. Probably not the 100th if you count the EU

Comment: Frankly, there's a reason I always call the Emperor "Palpatine" rather than "Sidious".

Comment: @WadCheber Better than "Sheev". And yes, that is Palpatine's canon name. Sheev Palpatine.

Comment: @Thunderforge And people wonder why he goes by "Palpatine." Ain't nobody going to respect "Emperor Sheev"

Comment: How can no one on the council know about the Kaminoans, anyway? Even if the planet has been erased from the Jedi archives, they're not exactly the only source of information in the galaxy. Kamino seems to have had contact with others, as Dexter Jettster was able to tell Obi-Wan. Does the Republic not have archives? Is there not a HoloNet  anymore?

Comment: If he's got no nose, how does he smell?

Comment: @Adamant I think Madame Jocasta [would disagree with you](https://youtu.be/iNlqt3pvRFg) on that front

Comment: @Valorum horrible.

Comment: @adamant - The 'Outer Rim' is like the wild west. Information about their activities is sparse.

Comment: @Valorum - I suppose… Even some rando restaurateur was able to tell him, though. They must really have poor data sharing if whole planets can exist that are only recorded in one place on a planet of 1 trillion people.

Comment: @Adamant - Except that he's not a random, he's Obi-Wan's friend, a former weapons dealer with knowledge of the Rim Worlds. In short, an expert consultant.