# Why wasn't Obi-Wan surprised or amused by meeting a new species in Attack of the Clones?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi

When in the Attack of the clones (Episode 2) of Star Wars Obi-Wan lands on Kamino and sees the Kaminoans for the first time (upon first contact on Kamino) he has no amusement whatsoever.

Assuming we know that the Kaminoans are familiar with the human race and probably a few others *(I don't know what species Master Sifo-Dyas was)* but Kenobi had never seen Kaminoans before. They are an absolutely new race for him to encounter.

Yet, he looks at them and speaks to them as though he had seen them before and was familiar with them.

Does this have to do with him being a Jedi? I know that I would be really amused to make first contact with a new race. Why wasn't Kenobi amused to meet a new species?

Comment: why is it assumed he has no knowledge of the race? To draw a rather poor analogy, I've never been to Russia, but I know Russian people exist. Just because I can't identify a Russian made military part, doesn't preclude me from knowing Russia exists

Comment: The film says so and the books too. He didn't know about them.

Comment: I can kinda figure out what you are asking, so I won't flag as unclear. But I recommend you make it more clear what you are asking.

Comment: This is a big strange universe, I'm sure Obi has encountered plenty of species he doesn't know... at some point the shock must wear off? He's an extremely well-traveled being, probably one of the most well traveled in the Universe as he's sent on all these trips by the Jedi Council with Qui-Gon and then by himself. He has to be used to strange things happening and still being polite.

Comment: Consider the Mos Eisley cantina scene.  If you can see a diverse tableau like that just by walking into a bar on a galactic backwater like Tatooine, incredulity at encountering yet another differently shaped person can't be the normal reaction of a typical citizen.  For a member of an elite galactic police force, even a raised eyebrow at such an encounter would be a surprise.

Comment: Why do you think he should be amused? 1) He is going to a planet he has never been to before, so he already expects to meet a new race, as any well-traveled citizen of the Republic would, and 2) Look at the great variety of species that can be found even in a backwater port like Mos Eisley. Star Wars makes quite clear that everyone meets new species every single day. What would be abnormal is if a Jedi acted surprised or amused at every new species he meets, as if he doesn't meet new species every single day.

Answer (score 15):

The official novelization suggests that Obi-Wan was more taken aback than the film lets on; it also suggests that he was deliberately concealing his feelings, which would presumably include any consternation about the Kaminoans' appearance (emphasis mine):

> Obi-Wan pushed back his hood, which had offered little protection from the driving rain, and brushed the water from his hair. Wiping his face, he turned to face the speaker, and then **he paused, caught by the image of the Kaminoan**.
>
> *[...]*
>
> The words finally distracted Obi-Wan from **his bemused perusal** of her strangely beautiful physique. "I'm expected?" he asked, doing little to hide his incredulity. How in the galaxy could these beings possibly have been expecting him?
>
> *[...]*
>
> Obi-Wan nodded and **tried to play it cool**, hiding the million questions buzzing about in his thoughts. After all these years? They were thinking that I wasn't coming?
>
> <sup>*Attack of the Clones: Official Novelization* Chapter 15</sup>

Bear in mind that the Kaminoans don't know that Obi-Wan is unfamiliar with them; as far as they know, he's a representative of one of their clients and, even though he may have never visited their planet before, they have every reason to believe that he's at least theoretically familiar with them.

For his part, Obi-Wan doesn't want the Kaminoans to think he's uncomfortable. He's very explicitly playing along with their mistake to pump them for information, and any suspicions he raises in their minds is going to jeopardize his mission. It would rather give the game away if he's openly gawking at them.

Though, all of that being the case, I would deeply question the assumption that he *should* be unduly shocked by their appearance. As I (and others) have mentioned in various comments: sure, he's meeting an entirely new species, but it's not like there [aren't](http://www.starwars.com/databank/gran) [stranger](http://www.starwars.com/databank/sy-snootles)-[looking](http://www.starwars.com/databank/nautolan) [creatures](http://www.starwars.com/databank/nautolan) [roaming](http://www.starwars.com/databank/fode-and-beed) [the](http://www.starwars.com/databank/bith) [galaxy](http://www.starwars.com/databank/besalisk). As a well-travelled galactic citizen, we can presume that Obi-Wan has seen his fair share of unusual alien species, and the Kaminoans are a relatively tame design; as noted in [a different question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114013/31051) on the site, they're not wholly dissimilar from other species he would be familiar with.

What's more, there's some indication that openly gawking at aliens is considered a social faux pas; consider this exchange from the canon novel *Thrawn*, where three characters discuss the titular alien (who is of a race never before seen in the galaxy at large):

> "I've never seen anything like that before," Driller continued. "What is he, some kind of Pantoran with an eye condition?"
>
> "Now, that's just rude," Juahir chided him. But she was staring at the strange being just as hard as he was. "Arihnda? Any ideas?"
>
> "Sure," Arihnda said. "Let's go over and ask."
>
> Juahir's gasp was audible even over the hum of conversation filling the ballroom. "You're kidding."
>
> <sup>*Thrawn* Chapter 10</sup>

Although this is admittedly set in the Imperial era, many years after Obi-Wan's encounter with the Kaminoans, this doesn't seem an unreasonable social rule for any period of galactic history, especially in the relatively cosmopolitan years of the Republic.

And if there's anything we know about Obi-Wan, it's that he's unfailingly polite.

Comment: What do you know, this is my thousandth answer. Not sure how to feel about that, but hey; milestone

Comment: So he had to hide all his amusement to play the role of he-who-was-expected?

Comment: @SovereignSun I wouldn't use the term "amusement", but yes; any surprise he'd have felt at meeting the Kaminoans would give away the fact that he wasn't supposed to be there, which would potentially jeopardize his mission. Then again, it also seems reasonable to suspect that he probably wasn't *that* surprised by them; sure they're a brand new species, but they're far from the strangest-looking aliens in *Star Wars*

Comment: I hope you aren't refererring to the Gungangs he and his Master Qui-Gon once came across on Naboo?

Comment: @SovereignSun I was actually picturing Dex, Obi-wan's four-armed, beer-bellied line cook friend, when I wrote that. But we could also consider the Dugs (like Sebulba from *Phantom Menace*), who walk on their hands, or the three-eyed [Gran](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gran), or the [Ithorians](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ithorian), or [Sy Snootles'](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sy_Snootles) species, or any of a multitude of others

Comment: "his bemused perusal of her strangely beautiful physique." Well, that doesn't make him sound like a creep or anything...

Comment: This can also be corroborated that he practically bluffed his way through his 'interview' with the prime minister. The female attendant assumed he knew everything about the army, and so did the prime minister. Talking about the units so blase as if Obi-Wan was supposed to know already. And Obi-Wan just went along with it the whole time. When the prime minister asked if he wanted to inspect the army himself, Obi-Wan just said "That's why I'm here", when actually he was looking for the bounty hunter.

Comment: The news that someone (apparently a dead Jedi Master) had secretly commissioned a clone army for the republic that had been in operation for a few years must have been a bigger shock than simply meeting a new species, yet Obi-Wan hid it well. Also, there are thousands of species in the galaxy, so Obi-Wan must have been used to meeting new aliens. And the Kaminoan physique wasn't that outlandish to him cos there is a dude (can't remember his name) on the Jedi Council who looks remarkably like a Kaminoan.

Comment: @ASH-Aisyah You're thinking of Master Poof (no, [seriously](http://www.starwars.com/databank/yarael-poof))

Comment: @TheDarkLord Well, to be fair, he is *very* repressed

Comment: @JasonBaker yeahp! That guy. On the Jedi Council, looks a lot like a Kaminoan...